# set telnet to use NTLM with command

Tags: windows-7, batch, telnet

To set telnet to use NTLM authentication you type in telnet and press enter then type set NTLM

How can I make it do this with a command. using telnet set ntlm for example does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the Telnet service.

In the Services snap-in, on the Telnet Properties dialog box, click the Log On tab.

In Log on as, click This account, and then type Local Service in the text box.

Type the Administrator account password in the Password and Confirm Password 
text boxes.

Click OK to save your changes.

Open the Registry Editor. Click Start, type regedit in the Start Search box, and then press ENTER.

If the User Account Control dialog box appears, confirm that the action it 
displays is what you want, and then click Continue.

In the navigation pane, find the key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/System/CurrentControlSet/Services/TlntSvr
In the details pane, double-click RequiredPrivileges.

In the Edit Multi-String dialog box, if SeTcbPrivilege is in the list, remove it.

Click OK to save your changes.
Restart the Telnet Server service. See Enable the Telnet Server Service.

Comment: By default, users that log on by using NTLM authentication to a remote Telnet server can use their administrative privileges.
When you connect to a Telnet server by using password authentication, the token is filtered based on the following three conditions:
Whether the security account used to start the Telnet service is either Local Service or LocalSystem. See the procedures below named To use the Local Service security account to run Telnet and To use the LocalSystem security account to run Telnet.

Whether the user account is a domain account or an account local to the Telnet server.